# Несоответствие кодировок при использовании MySQL Connector

Tags: mysql, c++-cli, mysqlconnector

При попытке отправить SQL-запрос на добавление данных в таблицу, `execute()` бросает исключение, что не может затолкать в таблицу кириллицу:

```
sql::Statement* stmt = nullptr;
sql::PreparedStatement* pstmt = nullptr;
sql::ResultSet* res = nullptr;
try {
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    conn = driver->connect(server, username, password);
    conn->setSchema("work");
    stmt = conn->createStatement();
    stmt->execute("INSERT INTO work.employer (surname, first_name, birth_date) VALUES ('Сидоров', 'Алексей', '12.12.12')");
    label_connection->Text = "Connected to " + textBoxServer->Text;
    btnJournal->Visible = true;
}
catch (sql::SQLException& eSQL) {
    
    label_connection->Text = gcnew String(eSQL.what());
}
```

Пробовал добавить информацию о кодировке следующим образом:

```
stmt->execute("SET NAMES utf8mb4");
stmt->execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
stmt->execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4");
```

Но проблему это не решает. В MySQL Workbench точно такой же SQL-запрос с кириллицей отлично работает и добавляет запись в базу.

Аналогично и при запросе на вывод информации я получаю кракозябры вместо кириллицы:

```
sql::Statement* stmt = nullptr;
sql::PreparedStatement* pstmt = nullptr;
sql::ResultSet* res = nullptr;
try {
    conn->setSchema("mfua");
    stmt = conn->createStatement();
    res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT discipline_name FROM mfua.disciplines");
    while (res->next()) {
        System::String^ item = gcnew System::String(res->getString("discipline_name").c_str());
        journal->cmbBoxGroup->Items->Add(item);
    }
}
catch (sql::SQLException& eSQL) {}
```

Подскажите, как подружить MySQL Connector с кириллицей, пожалуйста.

UPD. Исключение бросает следующего содержания: "Incorrect string value: '\xD1\xE8\xE4\xEx\F0\xEE...' for column 'surname' at row 1"

А запрос SELECT возвращает вот такого рода содержимое: "РњР°С‚РµРјР°С‚РёРєР°"

В настройках таблиц charset установлен "utf8mb4", collation - "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci"

Comment: А где текст исключения? Где приходящие из базы кракозябры? Всё это должно быть прямо в вопросе.

Comment: + запросы `status;`  `show VARIABLES LIKE '%CHAR%';` `show VARIABLES LIKE '%Coll%';`  `SHOW CREATE TABLE 'employer';`

Comment: попробуй перед `driver->connect(` вставить две строки `driver->setClientOption("charset", "utf8mb4");` и 
    `driver->setClientOption("collation", "utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci");`

А вообще да, правильнее было бы выяснить заранее кодировки и collation в твоих таблицах. А то так, наобум, сложно советовать что-то.

Comment: Добавление строк `conn->setClientOption("charset", "utf8mb4")` и `conn->setClientOption("collation", "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci")` (`conn->setClientOption("collation", "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci")`) не решает проблему, к сожалению. `setClientOption` - метод `sql::Connection`, а не `sql::Driver`